# How we can get the user name in snowflake DB when user sign in from the power BI service portal with AD account

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How we can get the user name in snowflake DB when the user signs in from the Power BI service portal with an AD account

IS there is any way from Snowflake DB we can get the Azure AD user details to sign in from Power BI Services

Select Current_USER

Comment: What credentials are you using to connecting from Power BI to snowflake? Not AAD right? So you don't know what the user is. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

From a Snowflake perspective you get the current user by using CURRENT_USER(): https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_user.html

Some other "CURRENT()"-functions from Snowflake can be found here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-all.html

E.g. you can also select your current account, your current region, your current session or your current warehouse.